# How to evenly spread some floats in a line using floatrow package?

Tags: floatrow, textwidth, linewidth

I am trying to spread evenly in a line three floats (tikzpictures) with captions so they will have equal distances along the line: the first should be at far left the second exactly at the midpoint of the line and the third one at the far right of the line with no success. I didn't find anything that could help me in the `floatrow` manual (May I missed it). If someone can help I will appreciate it. I am open for new suggestions as `floatrow` package is somehow old (from 2009 with no updates). I tried the `\makebox[s]` but with no success with floats.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,indention=0pt,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=no,textfont={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow,tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{floatrow}[3]
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
                    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2);
                    \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0) -- +(180:2) arc (180:108:2);
                    \foreach \x in {0,36,...,360} \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
            \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{$\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$}}
            
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth+\Xhsize/2]{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
                    \draw[fill=gray!50,step=0.75,line width=1pt] (0,1.5) grid (3,3.75) rectangle (0,1.5);
                    \draw[step=0.75, line width=1pt] (0,0) grid (3,1.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{$\dfrac{3}{5}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$}}
            
            \ffigbox[\Xhsize]{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
                    \foreach \x in {0,1} \draw[thick, fill=gray!50] (\x,0) rectangle (\x+1,3);
                    \draw[thick] (2,0) rectangle (3,3);
                    \draw[thick] (0,1.5) -- (3,1.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{$\dfrac{2}{3}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$}}
        \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `\subfloat` from the subcaption package.  The spacing is provided by `\hfill`.

Technically, to put the center `\subfloat` in the exact center, one should put the left `\subfloat` inside `\leavevmode\rlap{...}` and the right `\subfloat` inside `\llap{...}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,indention=0pt,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=no,textfont={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption,tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=empty}
    \subfloat[$\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]%
        \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2);
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0) -- +(180:2) arc (180:108:2);
        \foreach \x in {0,36,...,360} \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
      \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \hfill
     \subfloat[$\dfrac{3}{5}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw[fill=gray!50,step=0.75,line width=1pt] (0,1.5) grid (3,3.75) rectangle (0,1.5);
        \draw[step=0.75, line width=1pt] (0,0) grid (3,1.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \hfill
    \subfloat[$\dfrac{2}{3}=\dfrac{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}{\fbox{\phantom{\Large A}}}$]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \foreach \x in {0,1} \draw[thick, fill=gray!50] (\x,0) rectangle (\x+1,3);
        \draw[thick] (2,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \draw[thick] (0,1.5) -- (3,1.5);
      \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]